How to get the following inequality about order on $n$ and $d$?
Let $n>d>1$ be large enough integer. Define $n_0=\frac{n\log d}{d}$ and $p=\sqrt{\frac{d}{\log d}}$. Define
$$
\alpha(d)=\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}-2
$$
where note that $$2\frac{\log(\log d)}{\log d}\le \alpha(d) \le 4\frac{\log(\log d)}{\log d}.$$
Assume that $n_0>p$ (i.e., we have $n>\frac{d^{2.5}}{(\log d)^{1.5}}$). Fix $r>1$ be an integer such that
$$
p^r<n_0\le p^{r+1}.
$$
Question: How to show that for some universal constants $C, c>0$,
$$
\frac{1}{d^6p^{2(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+1}}\ge \frac{C d^{1.5}\log^{4.5}d}{cn^{2(2+\alpha(d))}}?
$$

My work is as follows.
The above inequality is equivalent to
$$
cn^{2(2+\alpha(d))}\ge C d^{7.5}(\log^{4.5}d)p^{2(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+1}
$$
Plug $p$, that is to show that
$$
cn^{2(2+\alpha(d))}\ge C d^{7.5}(\log^{4.5}d)(\frac{d}{\log d})^{(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+0.5}=C\frac{d^{(2+\alpha(d)(r+1)+8}}{(\log d)^{(2+\alpha(d)(r+1)-4}}
$$
Using the inequality about $n$, the above inequality is equivalent to
$$
cn^{2(2+\alpha(d))}>c\frac{d^{5(2+\alpha(d))}}{(\log d)^{3(2+\alpha(d))}}\ge C\frac{d^{(2+\alpha(d)(r+1)+8}}{(\log d)^{(2+\alpha(d)(r+1)-4}}
$$
So this is equivalent to
$$
d^{(2+\alpha(d))(5-2(r+1))+8}\ge (\log d)^{(2+\alpha(d))(3-(r+1))+4}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{d^6p^{2(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+1}}\ge \frac{C d^{1.5}\log^{4.5}d}{cn^{2(2+\alpha(d))}}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
F:=\frac{n^{2(2+\alpha(d))}}{d^{7.5}p^{2(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+1}\log^{4.5}d}\ge \frac{C}{c}
$$
So, let us consider $F$.
Since $p=\sqrt{\frac{d}{\log d}}$, we can write $F$ as
$$\begin{align}F&=\frac{n^{2(2+\alpha(d))}(\log d)^{(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))-4}}{d^{(r+1)(2+\alpha(d))+8}}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(n^2\bigg(\frac{\log d}{d}\bigg)^{r+1}\bigg)^{2+\alpha(d)}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(\frac{n^2}{p^{2r+2}}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}
\end{align}$$
Since $p^r<n_0\le p^{r+1}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{n_0}\lt \frac{1}{p^r}\le \frac{p}{n_0}$$ which implies
$$\bigg(\frac{n^2}{p^2n_0^2}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}\lt\bigg(\frac{n^2}{p^{2r+2}}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}\le\bigg(\frac{n^2}{n_0^2}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(\frac{d}{\log d}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}\lt\bigg(\frac{n^2}{p^{2r+2}}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}\le\bigg(\frac{d^2}{(\log d)^2}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}$$
So, we have
$$\frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(\frac{d}{\log d}\bigg)^{\frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}}\lt F\le \frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(\frac{d}{\log d}\bigg)^{\frac{2\log(4d)}{\log p}}$$
For sufficiently large $d$, we have
$$2\lt \frac{\log(4d)}{\log p}\lt 3$$
(see here)
Therefore, we get
$$\frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(\frac{d}{\log d}\bigg)^{2}\lt F\lt \frac{1}{d^8(\log d)^4}\bigg(\frac{d}{\log d}\bigg)^{6}$$
It follows from this that $\displaystyle\lim_{d\to\infty}F=0$, so we see that there are no such constants $c,C\gt 0$.

Thank you so much! Can we improved this lower bound (get one tighter bound)?

@Hermi : I'll try when I have time.

Thank you so much!
